# Find duplicate records in MySQL without named column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
**lead_id** **form_id** **field_number** **value**

1           2           1                Richard
1           2           2                Garriot

2           2           1                Hellen
2           2           2                Garriot

3           2           1                Richard
3           2           2                Douglas

4           2           1                Tomas
4           2           2                Anderson
```

Where `field_number = 1` is the name and `field_number = 2` is the surname.

I would like to find entries that are equal by name OR surname and group them by `lead_id`, so the output could be like this:

```
1
2
3
```

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Comment: I'm not sure you've thought through the implications of your requirement.  For a limited example, this would indeed return {1,2,3}. But for a large database consider the explosion that would occur.  You have first names {Richard, Hellen} and last names {Garriott, Douglas}.  In a large database this would also pull in all other first names "Hellen" _plus all associated last names in all those records_, and last names "Douglas", _plus all records matching any first names in the set of Douglas records_.  This would probably result in a large fraction of your database being marked duplicate.

Comment: @jim-garrison yes I had thought about it, unfortunately this is how the client requested the feature :|

Comment: Then it's part of your job to inform the client of the implications of their request and clarify what they _really_ want.  As soon as you hit a common first name or surname you'll pull in a huge number of records.  This cannot be what the client wants and you should explain this before wasting their time and money building something that doesn't do what they need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work and be reasonably efficient (depending upon indexes):

```
select distinct lead_id
from tablename as t1
where exists (
  select 1
  from tablename as t2
  where t1.field_number = t2.field_number
  and   t1.value = t2.value 
  and   t1.lead_id <> t2.lead_id 
  )
```

Comment: all right, I had to add one more line due to the field_number column which can have more than two values in my db, but it works! Thanks! Can I ask you why the `select 1` and `t1.field_number = t2.field_number` things?

Comment: Sure, happy to explain. [1] With `EXISTS` you only need a not-null value. There is no reason to select a particular column here, since we aren't using the actual value, so a constant of 1 is as good as any other value. Note that if there is no match in the sub-query, the result set is empty and `1` is not returned, so the `EXISTS` test fails. Other ways to do this would be `where 0 < ( select count(*) ...` [2] Can you clarify what you need explained regarding the `field_number` correlation?

Answer (score 0):

```
Select leadid from (
Select DISTINCT leadid,value from tablename
Where fieldnumber=1
Group by leadid,value
Having count(value) >1
Union all
Select DISTINCT leadid,value from tablename
Where fieldnumber=2
Group by leadid,value
Having count(value) >1
) as temp
```

Surely there is a faster option